# does GlassFish need much library for connect to the Oracle DB?

Tags: oracle11g, glassfish

I have glassfish 3, jsf (prime) , oracle 11g running  and using netbeans 8 on my machine, migrating process from postgress  (server 1) to oracle has been finished,   i want to get all of the data in the oracle 11g using jsf, i had change the library , add library ojbc6dms, rename my persistence-unit like my registered datapool, until finished that step, i deploy my project and get this :
WARNING: PWC6351: In TLD scanning, the supplied resource

```
file:/C:/project/lib/../../mq/lib/imq.jar does not exist
woodstox-osgi.jar  does not exist
tools.jar  does not exist
glassfish-corba-asm.jar  does not exist
glassfish-corba-codegen.jar  does not exist
glassfish-corba-csiv2-idl.jar  does not exist
glassfish-corba-newtimer.jar  does not exist
glassfish-corba-orb.jar  does not exist
glassfish-corba-orbgeneric.jar  does not exist
auto-depends.jar  does not exist
config.jar does not exist
hk2.jar does not exist
config-types.jar does not exist
hk2-core.jar does not exist
osgi-adapter.jar does not exist
tiger-types-osgi.jar does not exist
grizzly-comet.jar does not exist
grizzly-config.jar does not exist
grizzly-http.jar does not exist
grizzly-http-servlet.jar does not exist
grizzly-portunif.jar  does not exist
grizzly-rcm.jar does not exist
grizzly-utils.jar does not exist
pkg-client.jar does not exist
jaxb-osgi.jar does not exist
webservices-osgi.jar does not exist
activation.jar does not exist
el-api.jar  does not exist
mail.jar  does not exist
webservices-api-osgi.jar does not exist
jaxb-api-osgi.jar does not exist
junit.jar  does not exist
javax.persistence.jar does not exist
org.eclipse.persistence.antlr.jar does not exist
org.eclipse.persistence.asm.jar does not exist
org.eclipse.persistence.core.jar does not exist
org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jar does not exist
org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.jar does not exist
```

i know this problem can be solved by adding the library above, but why its have much library ?  Are that library should be needed to make one normal project for GlassFish oracle database?

Comment: These messages don't have anything to do with Oracle DB. They may indicate a misconfiguration of some kind in your Glassfish installation. But as none of those JAR files shoudl contain TLDs it's probably benign.

Comment: thank for the few edit, but until now my case isn't get finished.